Filtering extensive Terraform Data output
is there a way to filter out extensive terraform data source output, that doesn't have "built-in filter"? I am using DNACENTER provider, and specifically this data source.
When I run below:
data "dnacenter_file_namespace_files" "example" {
  provider   = dnacenter
  name_space = "nw_orch"
}

output "dnacenter_file_namespace_files_example" {
  value = data.dnacenter_file_namespace_files.example.items
}

I get output that looks like this:
Changes to Outputs:
  + dnacenter_file_namespace_files_example = {
      + id         = "1720985135"
      + items      = [
          + {
              + attribute_info   = ""
              + download_path    = "/file/a156b130-5c40-4227-a8b9-ab2cd8cc6ed6"
              + encrypted        = ""
              + file_format      = "text/csv"
              + file_size        = "87"
              + id               = "a156b130-5c40-4227-a8b9-ab2cd8cc6ed6"
              + md5_checksum     = "bc37d95c037bbf8f17ff704a9a445694"
              + name             = "site1.csv"
              + name_space       = "nw_orch"
              + sftp_server_list = [
                  + jsonencode(
                        {
                          + createTimeStamp = "05/12/2024 11:44:26"
                          + downloadurl     = "/nw_orch/a156b130-5c40-4227-a8b9-ab2cd8cc6ed6/site1.csv"
                          + id              = "d5bc91e7-58c4-4f65-b865-67e6a26bfa51"
                          + sftpserverid    = "18adcb51-ca12-4a9c-9e55-46e0743ee49e"
                          + status          = "SUCCESS"
                          + updateTimeStamp = "05/12/2024 11:44:26"
                        }
                    ),
                ]
              + sha1_checksum    = "a5b02a92d80850870abbc0a5ac6b169361c0efe9"
              + task_id          = ""
            },
          + {
              + attribute_info   = ""
              + download_path    = "/file/3e2079b8-d9be-4668-8ae2-16345e5b8388"
              + encrypted        = ""
              + file_format      = "text/csv"
              + file_size        = "93"
              + id               = "3e2079b8-d9be-4668-8ae2-16345e5b888"
              + md5_checksum     = "cab5fd8fea4b40e209b346ec76beed92"
              + name             = "site2.csv"
              + name_space       = "nw_orch"
              + sftp_server_list = [
                  + jsonencode(
                        {
                          + createTimeStamp = "07/14/2024 11:57:16"
                          + downloadurl     = "/nw_orch/3e2079b8-d9be-4668-8ae2-16345e5b8388/site2.csv"
                          + id              = "726d6c00-4dbd-4a0f-a8e5-59daba4e3eb4"
                          + sftpserverid    = "18adcb51-ca12-4a9c-9e55-46e0743ee49e"
                          + status          = "SUCCESS"
                          + updateTimeStamp = "07/14/2024 11:57:16"
                        }
                    ),
                ]
              + sha1_checksum    = "d162b5914e9633d16a09830143ffcd5f31a4019d"
              + task_id          = ""
            },
          + {
              + attribute_info   = ""
              + download_path    = "/file/47e0bd91-b415-49e7-aa34-e4879340ea76"
              + encrypted        = ""
              + file_format      = "text/csv"
              + file_size        = "93"
              + id               = "47e0bd91-b415-49e7-aa34-e4879340ea76"
              + md5_checksum     = "cab5fd8fea4b40e209b346ec76beed91"
              + name             = "LP3-lan_auto_device_v2.csv"
              + name_space       = "nw_orch"
              + sftp_server_list = [
                  + jsonencode(
                        {
                          + createTimeStamp = "07/14/2024 12:17:36"
                          + downloadurl     = "/nw_orch/47e0bd91-b415-49e7-aa34-e4879340ea76/LP3-lan_auto_device_v2.csv"
                          + id              = "162046ed-37d9-458a-adaf-3d2b188caf33"
                          + sftpserverid    = "18adcb51-ca12-4a9b-9e55-46e0743ee49e"
                          + status          = "SUCCESS"
                          + updateTimeStamp = "07/14/2024 12:17:36"
                        }
                    ),
                ]
              + sha1_checksum    = "d162b5914e9611d16a09830143ffcd5f31a4018d"
              + task_id          = ""
            },
        ]
      + name_space = "nw_orch"
    }

From this output I am only interested in the id of the file, which has a specific name, e.g. "site1.csv", which has this id "a156b130-5c40-4227-a8b9-ab2cd8cc6ed6". I can export all IDs:
data "dnacenter_file_namespace_files" "example" {
  provider   = dnacenter
  name_space = "nw_orch"
}

output "dnacenter_file_namespace_files_example" {
  value = data.dnacenter_file_namespace_files.example.items.*.id
}

and get something as below.
Changes to Outputs:
  + dnacenter_file_namespace_files_example = [
      + "a156b130-5c40-4227-a8b9-ab2cd8cc6ed6",
      + "47e0bd91-b415-49e7-aa34-e4879340ea76",
    ]

But can I use some filtering, or a condition to get only the ID of a file with a specific name?
Thanks!

How is the output defined in the first place?

Sorry about that, please see the updated post above how the outputs are defined.

I checked the documentation for the data source, it seems there's no filtering available. Would the ID be known beforehand?

No, its not known beforehand. This is why I ask if I can do some filtering using a condition and a file name, or something like that?

So you only want the IDs for all of the items?

You should be able to filter output from the data source using the for loop:
output "dnacenter_file_namespace_files_example" {
  value = [for item in data.dnacenter_file_namespace_files.example.items: item.id if item.name == "site1.csv"]
}

I can't test it right now for syntax correctness but I hope you will get the idea how it can be done.

Yes, that worked! Awesome, thanks Filip!
